# Не знаю откуда постоянно возникает эта ошибка с доступом в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Кто-нибудь может дать полную консультацию по поводу решения данной проблемы? Пробовал поставить $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = null, но это не помогло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Практически везде пишут что в большинстве помогает смена `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';` на `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`, а вы меняете `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']`? Но у вас проблема в mysql сервере, а не phpmyadmin. Покажите логи mysql